# error in overwrite `>` in julia

Tags: pipe, julia

I am trying to overwrite `>` in julia with the following

```
julia> (>)(a, f::Function) = (|>)(a, f)
> (generic function with 1 method)

julia> (>)(f::Function, g::Function) = (x...)->g(f(x...))
> (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> -2 > abs
2

julia> -2 > (abs > sqrt)
1.4142135623730951

julia> (-2 > abs) > sqrt
1.4142135623730951
```

So far it's working fine. Howerver, I could not figure out how to overwrite `>` for the following case:

```
julia> -2 > abs > sqrt
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (Int64) used in boolean context

julia> @which -2 > abs > sqrt
ERROR: expression is not a function call, or is too complex for @which to analyze; break it down to simpler parts if possible
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:21
```

Is it a buit-in hard syntax or is it a ternary function so that we can overwrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/mathematical-operations/#Chaining-comparisons-1 it follows that the problem is that `-2 > abs` is an `Int` and it is passed as LHS for `&&` which throws an error.

In general `>` is expected to return `Bool` and chaining comparisons rely on this fact. You would have to redefine how `&&` works. I would recommend using some other symbol than `>` for your purposes, e.g.:

```
julia>  ⊗(a, f::Function) = (|>)(a, f)
⊗ (generic function with 1 method)

julia>  ⊗(f::Function, g::Function) = (x...)->g(f(x...))
⊗ (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> -2 ⊗ abs ⊗ sqrt
1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! I will find another unicode operator as you suggested.